# Broken packages relating to Python 3.4

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, python

I recently tried to install ubuntu-desktop to a machine that had previously just had ubuntu server on it.  For some reason I am getting a message about broken packages.  I've tried following up on the packages that have "impossible" to satisfy dependencies and it all seems to lead back to python 3.4, but I've uninstalled/reinstalled it and nothing was changed, so I may be wrong on that.

Now all kinds of things aren't able to be installed, for example:

```
sudo apt-get install gedit
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gedit : Depends: libpeas-1.0-0 (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: python3-gi (>= 3.0) but it is not going to be installed
     Depends: gir1.2-peas-1.0 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried all the usual suggestions like "autoremove", clean, update, upgrade, etc.  To no avail.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Ok, i used aptitude to ask for some solutions when installing firefox (another package depending on python 3.4 that wasn't installing), and the following combination seemed to fix things:       Remove the following packages:                                                                             
1)      python3-minimal                                                                                          
2)      python3.4-minimal                                                                                        

and downgrading a lot of libpython packages.

Answer (score 0):

A [recent SRU](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+source/python3.4/+bug/1348954) went sideways. It has since been pulled but a lot of people have already been upgraded to python3.4 3.4.3. And now that it has been pulled, it's probably what's causing your dependency issues.

If aptitude is offering a *sane* downgrade plan to 3.2.0, go with it. If it isn't I'd suggest hanging on and monitoring that bug report for news about a fixed SRU update being made available.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was only a broken symlink, this fixed the issue:

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
```

then i was able to install new version